# Make a Toplevel window take up the entire monitor space?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, fullscreen, toplevel

I'm trying to make a tkinter Toplevel window to go full screen and take up the entire monitor space (going over the task bar as well). I am able to do this with the `Tk()` using the code: `window.attributes("-fullscreen", True)`. But I know you can't have two instances of `Tk()` so I need to use a Toplevel and `root.attributes("-fullscreen", True)` does not work with Toplevel.

The code I have in place at the moment to make the Toplevel fullscreen is this:

```
window = Toplevel()
 w = window.winfo_screenwidth()
 h = window.winfo_screenheight()
 window.geometry("%dx%d+0+0" % (w,h))
```

But this does not even go into a proper fullscreen mode as the left side of the interface does not reach the edge of the screen.

How can I get a Toplevel window to take up the entire space of the screen like a Tk() window can?

Answer (score 0):

I found a work around to this issue. What I did was I set the `Tk()` interface to take up the entire screen, and I placed a frame on top of it and made it fit the `Tk()`. That way I could put the desired widgets on the frame and when I'm done, destroy the frame and reset the size of the `Tk()` frame.

Answer (score 0):

This is a possible way to solve fullscreen trouble:

```
finestra1= Toplevel()
wf1= finestra1.winfo_screenwidth()
hf1= finestra1.winfo_screenheight()
A = str(wf1)
B = str(hf1)
finestra1.geometry(A+"x"+B)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. While this code may solve the question, including an explanation of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.  Have a look here → [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)